# Why doesn't "python3 [command]" do anything?

Tags: python, pip, discord.py

I am trying to use pip to install discord.py. When I simply type `pip install discord.py`, it defaults to 2.7 and complains that it needs 3.4+. When I say `python3 -m pip [command]`, nothing is printed to stdout, and as far as I can tell nothing happens at all. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The problem seems to extend to all python3 commands - "python3 --version" doesn't do anything either.

Comment: use `pip3 install discord.py`

Comment: What is `[command]`? `install discord.py`?

Comment: Yes, You need pip3 to install packages for Python3

Answer (score 1):

Resolution: I installed Python 3.8.0 earlier today. I restarted my computer, and now the default version has been changed to 3.8.0 and everything's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

check python version

```
python3 --version
```

if it is 3.5+ , good , then do in terminal

1. `python3` go to python prompt
2. `import pip` check if pip is there or not if not then install it 
   in ubuntu run command `sudo apt install python3-pip`

   verify again it is installed or not
3. then do `python3 -m pip install discord.py`

Answer (score 0):

try using python3 -m pip3 [command] instead. pip3 is used to install python 3 packages.

Comment: This shouldn't work. The module is named `pip`, not `pip3`. Though there might be a *script* called `pip3` which *calls or imports* the module `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using a virtual environment. So if you perform `virtualenv -p python3` you will have a python3 environment. Then `source bin/activate` then you should be able to successfully run pip 3 commands simply by using `pip install discord.py`. Hope this helps!